# Did the specific date Tony chose to go to the base have some significance?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony Stark and Steve Rogers go to...

> ...the Shield base in New Jersey, on a specific date in 1970.  Tony says it's a date that he knows that his father and Hank Pym will both be working there.

Why did Tony pick that day?  Picking the year seems obvious, but why that day?

I had guessed that perhaps...

> ...that is Tony's birthday, and he knows that his father had been at work right before he was born.

But I don't know if there's any way to verify that inside the MCU.

Edited to add: I'm not concerned with why they would go there (that seems obvious, and the other question addresses it); I'm asking about the specific month and day Tony chose.

Comment: _”Is there anything special about this place and time and how did they both know about it?”_ this is covered in the duplicate.

Comment: As I said, it's pretty clear why they picked 1970.  But when Tony whispers the idea to Steve (while Scott is still there), he gives him a specific month, day and year.  I know why they know the Tesseract and Pym particles would be there.  I'm wondering if Tony chose that exact day because he *wanted* to see if he ran into his father on a specific occasion, covered in the spoiler tag, unrelated to the Tesseract.